# what is the need for .py and .kv files with kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am fairly new to kivy and am currently writing a simple fitness app for my A-level computing project.

I originally used simple instructions I found from different websites and this means I have now coded the majority of my app in only kivy language instead of having a .py file too (sorry if that makes little sense, I'm struggling to understand the concept of both the .py file and the .kv file)

Is it okay to just code in a 'kv.' type of file where I am mostly just using kivy language? Or do I need to learn how to create a .py file too for my app to work completely (as I have run into some issues such as using the scrolling widget and am wondering if this is to do with me not having a .py file as most solutions seem to be using a .py file.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no fundamental problem with using mostly or entirely kv files, if they do what you want.

I suggest asking a separate question about the specific issues you're hitting.